# CakePhp ControllerTest seems to be deleting Model Table

Tags: testing, cakephp-2.1

I'm just starting to use Phpunit with CakePhp2.0 when I run my first controller test against a very simple Model Items (id, title)

./Console/cake test app Controller/ItemsController

I haven't added any other tests than those from 'cake bake;. The tests pass, however, it blows away the associated item table.

I have the latest 2.x version.

Answer (score 1):

Dan,

I ran into this problem myself.  In your test class add:

class TestControllerTest extends ControllerTestCase {

```
public $dropTables = false;
```

}

Comment: Thanks Walter, funny that this would not be the default.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make the correct testing DB configuration in `app/Config/database.php` ?
There is a "$test" property there, that shows which database should Cake use for testing.
If it is the same as your default configuration (or inexistent) it will be pointing to your default database.

Comment: I'll take a look, the weird thing is, tests seem to run fine but then they drop the table of model its testing. Thanks and sorry for delayed response.